# An error occurs when I try to deploy jbpm-console.war on wildfly.8.1.0.Final (install.demo.noeclipse)

Tags: security, dns, wildfly, jbpm

I'm trying to change the "default" workbench security domain (other) but I have some problems. I modified all the standalone.xml files adding a new security domain called "myDomain" and deleting "other" security domain

```
<security-domains>
            <security-domain name="myDomain" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="UsersRoles" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/users.properties"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/roles.properties"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
        </security-domains>
```

And I modified the jboss-web.xml (on the jbpm-console)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC
    "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 2.4//EN"
    "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_4_2.dtd">

<jboss-web>

  <security-domain>myDomain</security-domain>

</jboss-web>
```

But when I try to deploy the jbpm-console.war an error occurs:

```
"{
\"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies\" => [
    \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.JMSAuditProcessor.CREATE is missing [jboss.ra.hornetq-ra]\",
    \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.KieSessionRequesMessageBean.CREATE is missing [jboss.ra.hornetq-ra]\",
    \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.TaskServiceRequesMessageBean.CREATE is missing [jboss.ra.hornetq-ra]\",
    \"jboss.naming.context.java.module.jbpm-console.jbpm-console.DefaultJMSConnectionFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.DefaultJMSConnectionFactory]\",
    \"jboss.naming.context.java.module.jbpm-console.jbpm-console.env.\\\"org.kie.remote.services.jms.RequestMessageBean\\\".factory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.JmsXA]\"
],
\"JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available.\" => {
    \"Services that were unable to start:\" => [
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".CdiValidatorFactoryService\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".WeldStartService\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.AlternativeStarterBean.START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.AlternativeStarterBean.WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.AlternativeStarterBean.WeldInterceptorBindingsService\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.AvailableJobsExecutor.START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.AvailableJobsExecutor.WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.AvailableJobsExecutor.WeldInterceptorBindingsService\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.CommandWebService.START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.CommandWebService.WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.ConfigServiceWatchServiceExecutorImpl.START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.ConfigServiceWatchServiceExecutorImpl.WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.ConfigServiceWatchServiceExecutorImpl.WeldInterceptorBindingsService\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForEachTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForTokensTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForTokensTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ImportTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ImportTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.OutTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.OutTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ParamTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ParamTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.RedirectTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.RedirectTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.SetTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.SetTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.UrlTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.UrlTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.WhenTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.WhenTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.BundleTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.BundleTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.FormatDateTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.FormatDateTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.FormatNumberTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.FormatNumberTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.MessageTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.MessageTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.ParamTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.ParamTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.ParseDateTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.ParseDateTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.ParseNumberTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.ParseNumberTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.RequestEncodingTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.RequestEncodingTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.SetBundleTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.SetBundleTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.SetLocaleTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.SetLocaleTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.SetTimeZoneTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.SetTimeZoneTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.TimeZoneTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.TimeZoneTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.DateParamTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.DateParamTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.ParamTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.ParamTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.QueryTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.QueryTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.SetDataSourceTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.SetDataSourceTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.TransactionTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.TransactionTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.UpdateTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.UpdateTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.xml.ExprTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.xml.ExprTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.xml.ParamTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.xml.ParamTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.xml.ParseTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.xml.ParseTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.xml.TransformTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.xml.TransformTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlFmtTLV\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlFmtTLV\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlSqlTLV\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlSqlTLV\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlXmlTLV\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlXmlTLV\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.drools.workbench.screens.dtablexls.backend.server.DecisionTableXLSFileServlet\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.drools.workbench.screens.dtablexls.backend.server.DecisionTableXLSFileServlet\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.drools.workbench.screens.scorecardxls.backend.server.ScoreCardXLSFileServlet\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.drools.workbench.screens.scorecardxls.backend.server.ScoreCardXLSFileServlet\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.guvnor.common.services.backend.archive.ArchiveServlet\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.guvnor.common.services.backend.archive.ArchiveServlet\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.M2Servlet\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.M2Servlet\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jboss.errai.bus.server.servlet.DefaultBlockingServlet\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jboss.errai.bus.server.servlet.DefaultBlockingServlet\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jboss.errai.bus.server.servlet.StandardAsyncServlet$1\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jboss.errai.bus.server.servlet.StandardAsyncServlet$1\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.bui.taglib.ImageResolverTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.bui.taglib.ImageResolverTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.designer.web.server.TransformerServlet\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.designer.web.server.UUIDBasedRepositoryServlet\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.designer.web.server.UUIDBasedRepositoryServlet\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.designer.web.server.menu.MenuConnectorServlet\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.designer.web.server.menu.MenuConnectorServlet\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.designer.web.server.menu.MenuServlet\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.designer.web.server.menu.MenuServlet\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.designer.web.stencilset.impl.StencilSetServiceServlet\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.designer.web.stencilset.impl.StencilSetServiceServlet\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.controller.ControllerServlet\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.controller.ControllerServlet\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.ContextTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.ContextTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.JSPIncludeTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.JSPIncludeTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.PaneTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.PaneTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.factory.BeanTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.factory.BeanTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.factory.CurrentComponentTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.factory.CurrentComponentTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.factory.EncodeTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.factory.EncodeTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.factory.FormURLTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.factory.FormURLTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.factory.HandlerTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.factory.HandlerTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.factory.ParamTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.factory.ParamTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.factory.PropertyTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.factory.PropertyTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.factory.URLTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.factory.URLTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.factory.UseComponentTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.factory.UseComponentTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.formatter.FormatterParamTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.formatter.FormatterParamTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.formatter.FormatterTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.formatter.FormatterTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.formatter.FragmentTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.formatter.FragmentTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.formatter.FragmentValueTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.jbpm.formModeler.service.bb.mvc.taglib.formatter.FragmentValueTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.josql.contrib.JoSQLJSPQueryTag\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.josql.contrib.JoSQLJSPQueryTag\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.kie.remote.services.rest.jaxb.DynamicJaxbContextFilter\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.kie.remote.services.rest.jaxb.DynamicJaxbContextFilter\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.kie.remote.services.ws.command.CommandWebServiceImpl\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.kie.remote.services.ws.command.CommandWebServiceImpl\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.uberfire.ext.plugin.backend.PluginMediaServlet\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.uberfire.ext.plugin.backend.PluginMediaServlet\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.uberfire.ext.security.server.BasicAuthSecurityFilter\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.uberfire.ext.security.server.BasicAuthSecurityFilter\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.uberfire.ext.security.server.LoginRedirectServlet\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.uberfire.ext.security.server.LoginRedirectServlet\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.uberfire.ext.security.server.SecureHeadersFilter\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.uberfire.ext.security.server.SecureHeadersFilter\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.uberfire.ext.security.server.SecurityIntegrationFilter\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.uberfire.ext.security.server.SecurityIntegrationFilter\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.uberfire.server.FileDownloadServlet\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.uberfire.server.FileDownloadServlet\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.uberfire.server.FileUploadServlet\\\".START\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".component.\\\"org.uberfire.server.FileUploadServlet\\\".WeldInstantiator\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".deploymentCompleteService\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".jndiDependencyService\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformation\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"jbpm-console.war\\\".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart\",
        \"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./jbpm-console\",
        \"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./jbpm-console.UndertowDeploymentInfoService\"
    ],
    \"Services that may be the cause:\" => [
        \"jboss.naming.context.java.JmsXA\",
        \"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.DefaultJMSConnectionFactory\",
        \"jboss.ra.hornetq-ra\",
        \"jboss.security.security-domain.other\"
    ]
}
```

}"

Answer (score 2):

In Jboss server configuration folder standalone.xml and standalone-full.xml will be there. As default standalone.xml only configured it will give the basic features but standalone-full.xml will provide the services like JMS ,Queue, clustring.

Since jbpm want to access server queue and JMS part so we need run jboss server in standalone-full.xml mode.

Answer (score 0):

Logs seem to indicate the war is still using "other" security domain:
\"jboss.security.security-domain.other\"